# Esconder ?id= da URL php

Tags: php, url

Existe alguma forma de esconder ?id=1 da URL? Gostaria de esconder isso para ninguém poder alterar pela URL, se possível não só criptografar, mas esconder mesmo. Tentei fazer por Ajax mas acho que andei meio longe!

Estou passando meu "id" da seguinte forma:

```
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="editar-equipe.php?'.$id.'">
   <td>'.$nome_equipe[$a].'</td>
   <td>'.$responsavel[$a].'</td>
   <td>'.$cidade[$a].'</td>
   <td class="text-right">'.$uf[$a].'</td>
</tr>
```

Eu preciso desse ID para saber qual equipe estou editando. Só que não gostaria de ter uma URL com o ?id= no final.

Comment: E como você identificaria o registro que precisa acessar? Como você gostaria que ficasse a URL?

Comment: Pode ser por exemplo: meusite.com.br/editar-pessoa

Comment: Certo, o usuário precisa de autenticação para acessar a página? Essa alteração seria os dados da própria pessoa ou poderia ser de qualquer uma?

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, confere aí por favor! Sim o usuário precisa tá logado para acessar a página.

Comment: A URL no formato `/editar-equipe/nome-da-equipe` seria válido? Se sim, pesquise por slugs e URL amigáveis.